# Whitespace appearing on some screen sizes

Tags: html, css

Am trying out web responsiveness on different screen sizes, it seems on some screen sizes like iphone XR and iphone 12 Pro, am having white space on the right and my header is overflowing and this is causing horizontal scrolling.
I've been trying to figure out where the problem is but I am unable to do so. What could be the problem with my code?

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}

.header-navss {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.logo-div {
  display: block;
}

#saved-faqs-Btn {
  display: none;
}

.login {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 1;
}

.login a {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2% 6%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-links {
  flex: 1;
}

.nav-links ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.nav-links ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-links ul li a {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgb(245, 247, 250);
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.nav-links ul li a:hover {
  /*box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(247, 253, 241, 0.945);*/
  background-color: rgba(11, 164, 235, 0.774)
}

.nav-links ul li a.active {
  color: rgb(24, 26, 29);
  background-color: aqua;
}

#showPopup,
#showPopup2 {
  /*background-color: rgba(253, 254, 255, 0.925);*/
  background: transparent;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: rgba(245, 233, 233, 0.979);
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid rgba(11, 164, 235, 0.774);
}

#showPopup2 {
  margin-left: 8px;
}

#showPopup:hover,
#showPopup2:hover {
  background-color: rgba(11, 164, 235, 0.774);
  color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}

nav .fa {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="header-navss">

  <nav>

    <div class="logo-div">

      <!--<button id="saved-faqs-Btn" onclick="displaySavedFAQs()">Saved FAQs</button>

          <h4>SaneFaqs</h4>-->

    </div>

    <div class="nav-links">

      <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" id="hideMenu"></i>

      <ul>

        <li><a href="#" class="active" onclick="activateLink(this)">Home</a></li>

        <li><a href="#section-2" onclick="activateLink(this)">About Us</a></li>

        <li><a href="#" onclick="activateLink(this)">Contact</a></li>

        <li><a href="#faq-section1" onclick="activateLink(this)">FAQs</a></li>

        <li><a id="ratingLink" href="#rating-section" onclick="activateLink(this)">Rate Us</a></li>

      </ul>

    </div>

    <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true" id="showMenu"></i>

  </nav>





  <div class="login">

    <button onclick="showPopup()" id="showPopup">Sign In</button>

    <button onclick="" id="showPopup2">Create account</button>

    <div id="name"><label for="">craig sane</label></div>

    <button id="sign-out">Sign Out</button>

  </div>

</header>
```